# Firebase test-lab uploaded APK does not specify a main launcher activity

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-tv, leanback, firebase-test-lab

i'm trying to running a test lab in firebase for my TV application, made with Leanback api and i have the following error message: "**The uploaded APK does not specify a main launcher activity.**"
The application manifest does specify a **LEANBACK_LAUNCHER** intent-filter and the application is published on the play store and it works fine.

Anyone have any suggestions about it?
Thank you so much

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

[image]

Comment: Same issue here, did you manage to resolve it?